# Why does a playground open to a blank screen that says "No editor" the first time I open it in Xcode 10?

Tags: xcode, playgrounds

I am following the App Development in Swift course in Apple iBooks and I've downloaded the course materials. The first time I open a playground from the Student Resources folder it opens up to a blank screen that says "No Editor." If I close it and reopen it, it works fine. However, having to open a playground twice every time is annoying. It does warn me in the beginning that "This is a file downloaded from the Internet," and I click "Trust and Open," but still it is always a blank screen the first time I open a new playground. Has anyone else had this issue? Is there a way to fix it? I am using Xcode 12.0.1 on macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking on playground file, try following
go to "Open another project"
and open playground workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the navigation menu on the top left corner of the app and then you can open the desired playground file. let me know if that works!!